# Image import in Haxe / Openfl

Tags: haxe

I want to import an image using Haxe, my image is big but it is 8 bits and it weighs 89kb. The problem occurs when I import it, because the size of the memory grows by 35mb. I suppose it is reserving memory for a 32bit image.
Any idea how to import an image of 8bits, without consuming so much memory?

Comment: Is your image a png or jpeg? Those formats are storage compressions. When you load a png it will unload into full memory size. But im not sure how OpenFL handles compression though, I don't know if openfl handles any gpu compressed image formats.

Comment: It's a png with alpha and 8bits, but I can covert it to other format. which format do you think can work best?

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenFLs system. I don't think any format matters if they unpack fully in memory. What are your targets? Also see: https://github.com/openfl/lime/issues/872

Comment: Only html5. I read the documentation and did not find anything related to the number of bits :(

Comment: Webgl ( if you're even using that ) supports a few compressed textures. But on targets that do not support those formats it will unpack regardless. You could ask about this in their irc chat and report back?

Answer (score 1):

Joshua answer the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47478690/image-import-in-haxe-openfl/47479897#47479897

> OpenFL currently uses 32-bit memory for images at runtime, regardless
>   of the original compression format. I believe there is an enhancement
>   task open right now to allow for 24-bit, 16-bit and other color
>   formats.